# rsync to windows (cygwin)

Tags: ssh, rsync

We have a windows file storage (don't ask) and now I want to rsync with the machine from Windows, Mac and Linux.

So I installed *freeSSHd* (login shell is set to `C:/cygwin64/bin/sh.exe`), set up certificates and testing from Linux the `test.dat` has 0 bytes:

```
ssh myuser@winmachinename "C:/cygwin64/bin/true.exe" > test.dat
```

Even double checking with actual output works fine:

```
ssh myuser@winmachinename "C:/cygwin64/bin/ls.exe" > test.dat
```

Now, when I call rsync:

```
rsync --progress -avz -e ssh myuser@winmachinename:/c/Users ~/test
```

it fails with:

```
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(174) [Receiver=3.1.0]
```

As far as reading the docs, this should not happen, when the first test is successful!?

I am by now out of ideas - any recommendations how to debug this?

**EDIT:**

```
| OS            | rsync version                             |
|:--------------|:------------------------------------------|               
| Windows       | rsync  version 3.0.9  protocol version 30 |
| Linux         | rsync  version 3.1.0  protocol version 31 |
```

Comment: How about `ssh myuser@winmachinename rsync --help` -- do you get the rsync usage output?

Comment: Yep, works like a charm

Comment: What versions of rsync do you have on each side? (first line of `rsync --version`)

Comment: See versions in edit

Comment: Try adding the option `--protocol=30` to your rsync command.

Comment: Not necessary. When adding `-vvvv` it actually reports: `(Client) Protocol versions: remote=30, negotiated=30`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been the path.

Since I have mysysgit in `PATH` (but not cygwin), `sh.exe` called executables from mysysgit and failed. When adding cygwin to `PATH` before mysysgit, the error disappears.

After that, I have a [new issue](https://superuser.com/questions/763424/rsync-stops-at-client-version).